# Visual Studio space before 'else' or 'while'

Tags: visual-studio-2013, formatting, spacing

In Visual Studio 2013 C/C++, when I use Ctrl+K,Ctrl+F to format my code, Visual Studio will auto add space before the keyword `else` or `while`.

example,

```
}else{
```

after format, it looks like:

```
} else{
```

How can I turn it off? Thanks!

in *Option->Text Editor->C/C++->Formatting->Spacing*, I had change all option,but nothing change.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMdnM.png)

Comment: why are you afraid of spaces? Reading more code and you'll see spaces help a lot on readability

Comment: Of course I need spaces, but a space after '{' make me unhappy.

Comment: Visual Studio is not happy when facing other spacing style than its own. I just sticked to SharpDevelop. Don't worry about others "dissing" your style; as long as you are consistent with it, it is absolutely no issue. As a matter of fact, I also hate the space before "else".

Answer (score 0):

You can change the format through Option->Text Editor->C/C++->Formatting->General. Make sure all the boxes are unchecked. After that **all** spacing will be turned off.

Though, spacing makes a program much easier to read and manage. Try to get use of it.

**Edit:** To answer OP's question, uncheck 'Insert space before opening brace of block' through *Option->Text Editor->C/C++->Formatting->Spacing*

Comment: Thanks. Some times I need VS to format my code, I just want it no auto add space 'else' or 'while', what should  I do?

Comment: Sorry that I misunderstood your question. In your case you may want to go to _Option->Text Editor->C/C++->Formatting->Spacing_ then uncheck the 'Insert space between opening brace of blocks' under 'Spacing for braces'

Comment: I am sorry it didn't have this choice box in my Visual Studio 2013 Option->Text Editor->C/C++->Formatting->Spacing->Spacing for braces.see https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMdnM.png

Comment: Well...there is indeed two more choices in the Visual Studio 2015 Community I am using. I am sorry that this didn't help. Maybe there is an another way.